# Jenkins Build periodically

Tags: jenkins

I currently have a job running from 7AM-2PM every 15 minutes Monday->Friday. It is defined so:

```
H/15 7-14 * * 1-5
```

How can I update this to start at 7:30AM instead of 7AM? I still want it to run every 15 minutes and run M->F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 expressions for this, something like this should work:

30-59/15  7    * *  1-5

*/15      8-14 * * 1-5

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that the box was multi-line. Thanks!